# PC shutdowns. Incorrect motherboard temp readings

Tags: cpu, power-supply, shutdown

I'm having an issue with my PC, it keeps shutting down without warning. It will not turn back on before power connections is unplugged. It also happens from BIOS.

I installed open hardware monitor and could see the temps for one of the motherboard sensors jumps like crazy. It's cleary an incorrect reading. I assume this is why it's shutting down and not because of a faulty PSU. Any advice?

open hardware monitor CPU temp readings

[image]

Comment: "It will not turn back on before power connections are unplugged." - This tells me the issue has absolutely nothing to do with the temperature of the processor. However, it still is worth a try to reseat the processor in the socket and apply a fresh coat of thermal paste.  The fact you have to unplug the power connections tells me it's the power supply and/or motherboard.  The purpose of reseating the processor is to verify it's not a simple socket issue.  Since you are doing that the thermal paste is easily performed.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I was in a hurry to read and screenshot the data, as the system are shutting down within few minutes. It's the tempature senor located on the montherboard.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a bad sensor on the motherboard.

You may either try to find some means of turning it off and making
it be ignored by the BIOS (not recommended), or have the motherboard
repaired by a professional (recommended).

You may also look on the website of the motherboard's manufacturer
for new drivers, especially for the BIOS and the Chipset,
before having the computer repaired.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but what happens if it crashed doing the update/flashing? It can run between 5-10 mins before it shutdown.

Comment: The only dangerous one is the BIOS update - you should do your best not to have a crash and not to use the wrong version. But if it happens, a repair-shop can get it going again.